# asp net Access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net

before publishing my website all works fine.
i have a reporter that lets the user to create rdlc report and can access it from visual basic to modify it's view. the problem shows up after deploying. can't access to the file that the report saves **System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied** i add for all users in IIS full control permission and i added DefaultAppPool (Identity:ApplicationPoolIdentity) and give it full control permission but nothing still access denied knowing that on save new file nothing saved.

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

```
Line 394:currentReportVersion = ReportVersion.Load(reportVersionId);           
Line 395:System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(MapPath(@"UserDefinedReports\" + currentReportVersion.ReportPhysicalName));


[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]
   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +1075
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +60
   SchoolWeb.ManageReports.gvReportVersions_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) in C:\Applications\SchoolSystem\SchoolWeb\ManageReports.aspx.cs:396
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +173
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +164
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +84
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804
```

**Please Guys I need your help.
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Have you given Read / Write access to `IIS_IUSRS` to that file?

Comment: yes i gave all users full control permission

Comment: So you have given Read / Write access to `Everyone` as a group? Or have you given specific access to `IIS_IUSRS`? As far as I know you need to give explicit access.

Comment: I have given explicit access for every user and for everyone as a group.

Comment: Are you deploying it on shared enviornment...??

Comment: I deploy it on my own computer under C:\inetpub\wwwroot\... iis version 8.5 the inetpub isn't shared